# Creating "screenshots" with HTML 5 and CSS 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create small thumbnails of HTML elements. I first thought using CSS 3 reflection, but it is limited to being only a reflection (and not a direct copy) and I can not move it from its standard position.

Then I thought using JavaScript to copy the HTML element entirely along with all its contents and apply CSS 3 transform to scale it down to a thumbnail. That works pretty well, but is kind of a hack.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this with JavaScript, HTML 5 and CSS 3. Flash, Java and such are not an option and it only needs to work in one browser.

Comment: Hm I don't think there's a different approach. If I were you, I'd go with the javascript copy idea.

Comment: Yap... Javascript seems the best for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use CSS3 transformation on a copied HTML element. It suits my situation well, I just wanted to make thumbnails of HTML elements.